# ItextSharp : Adding cells to table using loop

Tags: vb.net, itext

As I am new to ItextSharp, I am trying to change the existing functionality on how the cells are added to PdfPTable .. currently the cells are added row wise, I want them to be added column wise with the help of a loop.

There are two lists, the first list fills the first column, the second list fills the whole of second column. If the lists have unequal rowcount, I have to add empty cells against those columns.

I tried doing some research on web for this but couldnt find a suitable solution.

Can someone provide an example to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to answer with anything iText specific since this is more of a general programming problem. The basic idea is that you need to find the maximum count of the two lists, loop from zero to that maximum, and check each list to see if that value falls in range. If it is in range, use the value and if it isn't, create your empty cell. Below is a very simple implementation of this:

```
''//Two sample lists
Dim ListA As New List(Of String) From {"A", "B", "C"}
Dim ListB As New List(Of String) From {"Apple", "Bat"}

''//Find the maximum count of the two lists
Dim X = Math.Max(ListA.Count, ListB.Count)

''//Index notations are zero-based so loop from zero to one
''//less than the total
For I = 0 To (X - 1)


    If I >= ListA.Count Then
        ''//Our index is past the limit of the first column, add empty cell here
        Console.WriteLine("<A>")
    Else
        ''//Our index is within the limits of the first column
        Console.WriteLine(ListA(I))
    End If

    If I >= ListB.Count Then
        ''//Our index is past the limit of the second column, add empty cell here
        Console.WriteLine("<B>")
    Else
        ''//Our index is within the limits of the first column
        Console.WriteLine(ListB(I))
    End If

Next
```

**EDIT**
If you have more than just two columns you can extrapolate this to something like the below:

```
Dim ListA As New List(Of String) From {"A", "B", "C"}
Dim ListB As New List(Of String) From {"Apple", "Bat"}
Dim ListC As New List(Of String) From {"Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "Daniel"}


Dim AllLists As New List(Of IEnumerable(Of Object))
AllLists.Add(ListA)
AllLists.Add(ListB)
AllLists.Add(ListC)
Dim Z = AllLists.Max(Function(l) l.Count)


For I = 0 To (Z - 1)
    For Each L In AllLists
        If I >= L.Count Then
            Console.WriteLine("<BLANK>")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine(L(I).ToString())
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Chris for replying.. This seems to be very decent solution for unequal arrays.. but about ITextSharp question.. there isnt any way we can do, filling the first column first and then second using a loop?

Comment: No. Just like in HTML, cells are added left to right, top to bottom. In reality, tables don't really have "rows" or "columns", they just have "cells". The column count is essentially just a number for the renderer to loop from one to that number and when it is reached, reset the `x` position.